# Parsed the XML data can't be shown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get data from an xml tree which is coming from an online RSS feed. While I put that in the loop then the data can't be shown up.

This is a normal HTML file. I am trying to append the data in a table using javascript.

```
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

x.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms", true);

x.onreadystatechange = function () {


  if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = x.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Link</th><th>Description</th> <th>Title</th></tr>";
    var data = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    console.log(data);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

   }
};

x.send(null);
```

Please see the below screenshot what I am getting,

[Here I am getting all the items which I need to show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGS8G.png)

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAwH3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use x but this.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

x.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms", true);

x.onreadystatechange = function () {


  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = this.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Link</th><th>Description</th> <th>Title</th></tr>";
    var data = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    console.log(data);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

   }
};

x.send(null);
```

Comment: Same thing is happening. If I  use doc.getElementsByTagName("channel"); - then I get one data under it. I want all the <item> which is under channel. Please look into it. Please take the reference from https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms. @iamousseni

Answer (score 0):

I found issue with data as third object in list description is undefined so this error so you can change your script like to validate data first

```
<script>
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

x.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms", true);

x.onreadystatechange = function () {


  if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = x.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Link</th><th>Description</th> <th>Title</th></tr>";
    var data = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    console.log(data);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
(data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0] && data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0]?
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
:'na')+
    "</td><td>" +
data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0] && data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0]?
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
:'na' +
    "</td></tr>";
console.log("print for loop-",i)
  }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

   }
};

x.send(null);
</script>
```

Updated

```
<script>
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

    x.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms", true);

    x.onreadystatechange = function () {


      if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200) {
        var doc = x.responseXML;
        var table = "<thead><tr><th>Link</th><th>Description</th> <th>Title</th></tr></thead>";
        var data = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

        console.log(data);
        table += "<tbody>"
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          table += "<tr>"
          table += "<td>" +
            (data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0] && data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0]
              .childNodes[0].nodeValue ?
              data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : "na") +
            "</td>";

          table += " <td>" +
            (data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0] && data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0]
              .childNodes[0] ?
              data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue :
              'na') +
            "</td>";

          table += "<td>" +
            (data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0] && data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0]
              .childNodes[0] ?
              data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue :
              'na') + "</td>";
          table += "</tr>";

          console.log("print for loop-", i)
        }
        table += "</tbody>"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

      }
    };

    x.send(null);
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi Amit

Here I am getting only titles. Can't get description and links. Would you please help.

Comment: At a time I can get only one data(title, link or desc).Not all at a time. And that too I am getting in one coloum. @amit Senger

Comment: sure i'm updating my existing answer

Comment: Thanks, I got that already. There was a bracket missing. @amit sengar

Comment: if your issue resolved then please mark answer otherwise this question will display in unanswered list

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the URI was right? Try this.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

x.open("GET", "https://www.gadgetsnow.com/rssfeeds/2147478039.cms", true);

x.onreadystatechange = function () {


  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = this.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Link</th><th>Description</th> <th>Title</th></tr>";
    var data = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel");

    console.log(data);

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    data[i].getElementsByTagName("link")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
     data[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

   }
};

x.send(null);
```